# How to server an image from a blob in gae in bottle.py

Tags: python, google-app-engine, bottle

I want to do something like the following (from the [GAE guestbook example](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/usingimages)) to dynamically server images from Blob properties in bottle.py

```
class Image(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    greeting = db.get(self.request.get('img_id'))
    if greeting.avatar:
      self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/png'
      self.response.out.write(greeting.avatar)
    else:
      self.error(404)
```

There seems to be no response.out though so this is what I have so far:

```
@get('/image')
def get_image():
  greeting = db.get(request.query.img_id)
  if greeting.avatar:
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/png'
    response.body = greeting.avatar
    return response
  else:
    abort('404', not found!)
```

but that isn't returning the image correctly.

EDIT: I was returning the request, not the response, so the above example works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using the HTTPReponse object:

```
@get('/image')
def get_image():
  greeting = db.get(request.query.img_id)
  if greeting.avatar:
    headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'image/png'
    }
    body = greeting.avatar
    return HTTPResponse(body, **headers)
  else:
    abort('404', not found!)
```